# ImageView background color based on % height

Tags: android, background, background-color

I am setting `red` background color in below image. So, it applies `red` color in full background. But now, I want to apply `red` color based on given height like 30% of image or say 70% of image. So, it should apply color from bottom to top only for 30% or 70% height. I tried it using `LinearLayout` params but it is resizing image instead of just background color. How can I do this ?
Here, Inner part of border is transparent and outside part of border is white so it will apply background color only in inner side.

[image: Shape]

Comment: If u look very closely, u can see that the circle isn't perfectly round! XD

Comment: @Strider, this is for example and it doesn't matter. Inner part of border is transparent and outside part of border is white so it will apply background color only in inner side.

Comment: Haha, I was just kidding :P

Comment: @Strider, hahahaa... Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue myself. I used `RelativeLayout` with `View` and `ImageView`. `View` with background color and based on height. Check below xml :

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <View
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@color/red" >
                </View>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="350dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_image" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```